# TYPO3 Repository completely deleting

Tags: typo3

I have typo3 version 7.6.18. $this->someRepository->remove($object);
it's just set delete = 1 in DB. I need remove completely, using repository query. Is it possible? How to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just avoid defining `delete` option in `ctrl` section of TCA for your table. This is the flag that toggles "soft deletion" which is what you are encountering.

Comment: Official TYPO3 Documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/Delete.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `$this->someRepository->removeAll();` this function removes all objects from repository as says the official documentation of TYPO3 in [this](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_repository.html#a521979edc6ecc9d48f60892bedb52df0) link.